# Antlr4 parse number failed

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to use antlr4 to parse number (double and integer), but fail to success. Hope some one can help me.

My Test code is:

```
public class TestAntlr4 {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        String input = "30";

        CharStream inputCharStream = new ANTLRInputStream(new StringReader(input));
        // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
        TokenSource tokenSource = new GqlLexer(inputCharStream);
        // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
        TokenStream inputTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(tokenSource);

        // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
        TestAntlr4Parser parser = new TestAntlr4Parser(inputTokenStream);

        parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
        parser.addErrorListener(new VerboseListener());

        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);

        NumberContext context = parser.number();

        System.out.println(context.toString());
    }
}
```

My antlr4 grammar is:

```
grammar TestAntlr4 ;


number
    : INT_NUMBER
    | DOUBLE_NUMBER ;

DOUBLE_NUMBER
    : ('+'|'-')? INTEGER '.' INTEGER? ;

INT_NUMBER
    : ('+'|'-')? INTEGER ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

fragment INTEGER
    : '0'
    | '1'..'9' ('0'..'9')* ;

fragment DIGIT
    : [0-9] ;
```

The result is:

```
rule stack: [number]
line 1:0 at [@0,0:1='30',<31>,1:0]: mismatched input '30' expecting {DOUBLE_NUMBER, INT_NUMBER}
[]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: See updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar seems to be okay.  Lexes and parses fine for me with input "30":

```
[@0,0:1='30',<INT_NUMBER>,1:0]
[@1,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]
```

Tried also with a double:

```
[@0,0:6='30.3343',<DOUBLE_NUMBER>,1:0]
[@1,7:6='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:7]
```

Parses just fine.

Now, in my environment I'm using the C# target, so my code is a little different from yours.

My (C#) code using the visitor pattern:

```
                AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
                Grammar1Lexer lexer = new Grammar1Lexer(inputStream);
                CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
                Grammar1Parser parser = new Grammar1Parser(tokenStream);
                IParseTree tree = parser.number(); 
                Grammar1Visitor visitor = new Grammar1Visitor();
                visitor.Visit(tree);
```

Compiles and works just fine.

UPDATE:

**I noticed that your lexer and your parser are named differently**, could you have a simple copy/paste error?  Usually when you generate the classes all are named uniformly based on your grammar's name.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, and you really solve my problem. Actually I encounter a antrl4 problem in my real project, and I simple the gramma for test but there is a mistake when copy and modify the unit test code. Nice observation! When I correct the Lexer it work:  >   TokenSource tokenSource = new TestAntlr4Lexer(inputCharStream);